# Two rings...are they isomorphic?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, local-rings

**Edit**:  I have reverted my question to its original version (which Bjorn Pooenen answered correctly) as requested in the comments.

Consider the local rings

$$R = \mathbb{C}[[x,y,z]]/\langle xy+xz+yz\rangle$$

and

$$S = \mathbb{C}[[x,y,z]]/\langle xy+xz+yz+xyz\rangle.$$

Is $R$ isomorphic to $S$?

**Some context**:  I am trying to understand formal neighborhoods of points on certain varieties.  I expect one answer, and I'm getting a different answer.  This is the first nontrivial case where the answer that I get does not obviously agree with the answer that I expect.

Comment: What's the dimension of $\mathfrak{m}^3/\mathfrak{m}^4$ in both cases?  Not an answer, just the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Both rings become isomorphic after passing to the associated graded of the filtration by powers of the maximal ideal.  Geometrically, this is the statement that Spec(R) and Spec(S) have isomorphic tangent cones (at their unique closed points).

Comment: Nick, out of curiosity, what was leading you to a different answer than what you expected?

Comment: Given a hyperplane arrangement A, one can associate a certain variety X(A), called the "reciprocal plane" of A.  This variety has a stratification by flats F of A.  The closure of the F-stratum is isomorphic to X(A_F) (the localized arrangement).  I want it to be the case that this stratum has a normal slice isomorphic to X(A^F) (the restricted arrangement), at least formally.  I can produce a normal slice, but rather than obtaining X(A^F), I'm obtaining a deformation thereof.  I'm hoping that this deformation is isomorphic to X(A^F), at least in a formal neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: You might want to say what $t$ is. (You mentioned it in your comment to Bjorn's answer, but it really needs to be in the statement of your question. I originally assumed it was a new variable.)

Comment: @Joe Silverman: Thanks, that was a typo!  I meant to leave t out of the main question.

Comment: Since I've already made the edit, I'm going to let it stand, but I promise not to change the problem again!

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to roll back the edit, accept Bjorn's answer, and create a separate question for the new pair of rings. The way it is done now makes Bjorn's answer hanging there without any context, it is very misleading.

Comment: I completely agree with Vladimir Dotsenko.

Comment: @NicholasProudfoot, please do revert the edit and ask another question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, they are isomorphic.

More generally, if $k$ is any algebraically closed field of characteristic not $2$, and $n$ is given, then all $k$-algebras of the form $k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]/(f_2+f_3+\cdots)$, where each $f_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$, and $f_2$ is a nondegenerate quadratic form, are isomorphic.  (I.e., there is only one kind of ordinary double point.)

You can construct an isomorphism to $k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]/(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)$ with your bare hands as follows.  First diagonalize the quadratic form to assume that $f_2=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$.  Let $m$ be the lowest degree monomial of degree greater than $2$.  Then $m$ is divisible by some $x_i$, say $m=x_1 g$.  Performing the analytic change of variable $x_1 \mapsto x_1-g/2$ eliminates $m$ at the expense of introducing new terms of even higher degree.  By iterating, one can eventually eliminate all monomials of degree 3 to obtain $f_3=0$, and then $f_4=0$, etc.  The partial compositions of this sequence of analytic coordinate changes converge to a single analytic coordinate change because they stabilize modulo any given power of the maximal ideal.

Comment: Prop. 2.4 and Prop. 2.8 in Ch. III of the book on etale cohomology by Freitag & Kiehl give a version valid with $k$ replaced by any complete local noetherian ring with separably closed residue field, permitting residue characteristic 2 provided $n$ is even in such cases (and using the usual notion of non-degeneracy in such cases).  The method rests on the implicit function theorem (similar to the above away from residue characteristic 2).  Of course, it is understood that the isomorphism is one of $k$-algebras, as seems to be implicit in the original question (though not stated).

Comment: Followup to comment from user52824: And in fact, the Freitag-Kiehl assumptions on $k$ are needed only to put the quadratic form $f_2$ into a standard form.  For any commutative ring $k$ and any $n$, all $k$-algebras of the form $k[[x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_n,y_n]]/(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j y_j + \sum_{i \ge 3} f_i)$ (with $f_i$ homogeneous of degree $i$) are isomorphic, by the same kind of proof as the one I sketched.

Comment: Bjorn:  Thanks, this does answer my question, but I realize the example I picked was too simple.  The next case that I would want to consider would be k[[x,y,z,w]]/<xyz+xyw+xzw+yzw+txyzw>, where t=0 or 1.  And you can imagine how this generalizes to n variables.  Is there any comparable trick for examples like this, or is it entirely specific to quadratic forms?

Comment: I've now edited the question with this trickier example.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the analogous result in converent power series is the Morse Lemma. http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/morselemma.pdf

Comment: Not all nondegenerate quadratic forms over $\mathbb{C}$ can be diagonalized

Comment: @Qfwfq: Yes, they can. Or are you talking of something different? One can always recall the standard proof. If $q$ is your non-degenerate quadratic form over a finite dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$, you can find a $v \in V$ such that $q(v) \neq 0$ (otherwise $q=0$ and is already diagonal), and even such that $q(v)=1$. The orthogonal space $W$ of $v$ for $q$ has dimension $dim V-1$ since $q$ is non-degenerate and does not contain $v$. Hence to diagonalize $q$ on $V$ it is enough to do so by $W$, which is already done by induction.

Comment: @Qfwfq: not every symmetric matrix can be diagonalised by conjugation $X\mapsto A^{-1}XA$, but the action of $GL(V)$ on quadratic forms is given by $X\mapsto A^TXA$. This action allows to proceed with Joël's argument over any field of characteristic not 2 where you can extract square roots of any element. (Characteristic is needed to have a 1-to-1 correspondence between quadratic and bilinear form to talk of orthogonal complement, square roots - to ensure $q(v)=1$).

Comment: @NicholasProudfoot: You could have a look to the book "Singularities of differentiable maps", by Arnol'd, Gusein-Zade and Varchenko, a large part of which is devoted to the study of such problems.